# prettus validator not validate date properly

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Here is my validation rule:

```
ValidatorInterface::RULE_UPDATE => [
    'date_of_birth' => 'date_format:Y-m-d'
],
```

But if pass date like this: Year-11-24

is not validating and generate error. I am  using https://packagist.org/packages/prettus/laravel-validation

**Error** is:

Could not parse 'Year-11-24': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (Year-11-24) at position 0 (Y): The timezone could not be found in the database

rather than that it must generate some error message

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @AmitMerchant added error above

Comment: should you convert the `Year` to `2020`?

Comment: @codeformoney: i need to generate error if wrong format of date passed

Comment: I thin in **laravel validator** you can do like this `'date_of_birth' => 'date|format:Y-m-d'`

Comment: Try using `'date_format:Y-m-d T'` where `T` checks for the timezone. This is because the error is related to the timezone.

Comment: or try this first in your controller. `$request->validate(['date_of_birth' => 'date|format:Y-m-d'])` if it work try to manipulate the code to the needs of your `package`

Comment: @AmitMerchant The date of birth does not match the format Y-m-d T

Comment: @codeformoney "Method Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator::validateFormat does not exist.

Comment: what laravel version are you using?

Comment: @codeformoney laravel 7.18

Comment: Heres what i did and also the out put https://imgur.com/a/UzRWjbp